# Why does my webpack compiled code have references to coinbase wallet and ethereum?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I was trying to figure out why my compiled js code using webpack had the following error in the console?

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'ethereum' of object '#'

When I look at the code that generated the error I see a bunch of references to CoinbaseWalletAPI and Ethereum... It seems to be in a small module called requestProvider.js. Has anyone ran into this before? I have not been able to find any references to this error online. When I looked up that NPM module I found this page(https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-provider), I'm assuming one of my modules in my project is including requestProvider but I do not know which one and I cannot find references in the source code in my node modules folder.

Comment: might want to try https://github.com/amio/npm-why to see why it's installed.

Comment: You probably know this, but it's almost certainly malicious (using your app to mine or something). You can use `npm ls request-provider` to see which packages depend on `request-provider`.

Comment: Thank you! I’ll give those a try and see what package is using it. (I will say, the error I saw is actually present in a lot of websites that use webpack to compile. I noticed it in the console for my UniFi controller on my network.

Comment: It has nothing to do with webpack. Webpack just builds your app, which bundles all of your imported packages in the process. If your app has a malicious package, webpack will include it. It could even be that the package hides all of its malicious activity during development and only activates in the production/built version. So you won't necessarily see the same errors in dev.

Comment: If you end up finding malware in a package, [report it](https://docs.npmjs.com/reporting-malware-in-an-npm-package) to npm and share your answer here.